# Reference to any last gameobject unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

if I click on the object A, the child of Object A appears. If I touch on the object B, the child of Object B appears but the child of last clicked (Object A or C or D etc...) disappears at same time too.

There is a way to reference to last any touched/clicked/collided gameobject ? I saw that before we could use EventSystem.SetSelectedGameObject but I don't know if it is obsolete or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add tags to object A, B and all the other objects, so your future code knows which one is which.

Second, we add this code:

```
void Start()
{
if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("LastObj")
PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("LastObj");
if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("TimesPressed")
PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("TimePressed");
}

public void buttpress(){
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("TimePressed", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TimePressed")+1);

if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("TimePressed")==1)
{
//Your first time code here
}else
this.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);

if(   GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastObj")) != null)
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(PlayerPrefs.GetString("LastObj")).gameObject.SetActive(false);

PlayerPrefs.SetString("LastObj",this.gameObject.tag);

}
```

I am writing from phone and hopefully I made no mistakes. Write this code and add it to your objects. And do so that when clicked, this function is called.

What I did there is this:

1. it activates the first object.
2. gets tag that has been saved in a Playerprefs and deactivate it.
3. save current Object's tag in Playerprefs.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. To understand, this code call function once time we press something, the child object appears and the last child disappears. 
What if the first child objects, that is setactive(false) at the first time, appears when we press to "true" and then we continue with this function ?

Comment: Code doesn't work? Wait let me change something in the code.

Comment: Ok. I changed the code a little bit. I left a space for you to write your first time code. Because I didn't get what you wanted. So.

Comment: Thank you. And the child object have to be hidden first (uncheck in inspector) before launching the script ?

Comment: You welcome. And yes.it should be unchecked